# Count distinct users based on timeDiff between last action and max slicer date

Tags: powerbi

I have the following dataset:

```
user_id, login_date
111, 01/02/2021
222, 02/15/2021
444, 02/20/2021
555, 01/15/2021
222, 03/10/2021
444, 03/11/2021
```

I want to count of the number of unique active user_id in the last 7 days based on the max date of my date slicer. I need this to be able to work with a KPI visualization. I have the table above and a calendar table I've created.

I've tried many formulas but basically here is what I have today:

[image]

I'm not sure what should be my next step.

Here is the the sample PBI report I'm working with

[report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IrJJ9TjYHH3NqRtQjd6TNb57VZ9oPq2Z/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **"users[login date]"** column instead of **"date table[date]"** in your trend axis of KPI visual and below measure you can use in Indicator.

```
 Last_seven_day_count =
VAR _max_selected_date =
    MAX ( 'Date Table'[Date] )
VAR _last_seven_day = _max_selected_date - 7
VAR _result =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( users[User ID] ),
        users[Login Date] >= _last_seven_day,
        users[Login Date] <= _max_selected_date
    )
RETURN
    _result
```

Refer below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the Calculate and distinct count is working in this case.

Comment: Calculate evaluates the expression based on provided filters. So as we need unique user id's in last 7 days in this case we have used Distinctcount as expression which provide us unique user id and we have added filter as date range based on selected date in slicer.